# Is it possible for a moving body to have no kinetic energy? If yes, then how?

Tags: energy, kinematics, reference-frames

An object which is moving relative to your coordinate system has [kinetic energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy) in that coordinate system; it does not have kinetic energy in a coordinate system which is stationary relative to the object. But, I am interested in same frame and not relative frames.

Comment: No, by definition.

Answer (score 8):

Kinetic energy is a positive-definite quadratic form in the velocities, so as soon as one part of your mechanical system is moving (i.e. it has a non-zero velocity vector in your frame of reference) you get a non-zero value.

Answer (score 1):

There is a scenario where this could happen which doesn't violate any known basic principles of physics, but it requires the existence of negative mass so it's unclear if the scenario is actually possible in the real world. But if negative mass exists, suppose we have a system composed of a positive mass and a negative mass, with the same absolute value so that the total mass of the system was zero. It can be shown that in both Newtonian physics and in general relativity that the negative mass will be gravitationally attracted to the positive one, while the positive mass will be gravitational repelled by the negative one. This has the strange consequence that a positive mass and a negative mass placed together could continually accelerate in one direction, with the positive mass in the lead, continually fleeing the negative mass, and the negative mass in the rear, continually chasing the positive mass, the distance between them remaining constant. Since this could only work if the masses had equal absolute values and the total mass was zero, this wouldn't violate conservation of energy since the total kinetic energy of the system would remain zero at all times.

For reference, see [this article](http://www.npl.washington.edu/AV/altvw14.html) by physicist John Cramer:

> But Newton's theory of gravity can't really be used as a reliable
>   guide to the effects of negative mass, because we know that it is only
>   an approximation to the best gravity theory we have, Einstein's
>   general theory of relativity. Fortunately for this discussion general
>   relativity was used in the late 1950's by the British physicist Sir
>   Hermann Bondi to investigate the effects of negative mass. Bondi
>   pointed out that when general relativity is considered purely as a
>   theory of gravity, mass never actually appears. It first appears when
>   the equations are solved in a way devised by the German physicist K.
>   Schwartzschild. Then mass appears as a constant of integration. Bondi
>   noticed that this mass constant could be made either positive or
>   negative. He was able to show that when m is made negative, both the
>   inertial and the gravitational mass effects are reversed. The results
>   of Bondi's calculations can be summarized in a few words: a positive
>   mass attracts all nearby masses whether positive or negative; an
>   negative mass repels all nearby masses whether positive or negative.
>
> It is not hard to interpret Bondi's result using Newtonian gravity.
>   Consider first a small negative mass $\textbf{m}_-$ in the field of a
>   nearby large positive mass $\textbf{M}_+$. Because $\textbf{m}_-$ has
>   negative gravitational mass, the gravitational force on it is reversed
>   and pushes away from $\textbf{M}_+$. But because $\textbf{m}_-$ also
>   has negative inertial mass, it responds to this force perversely, so
>   that it is accelerated toward rather than away from $\textbf{M}_+$.
>   The double change in sign (gravitational and inertial) results in no
>   change on observed effect and attraction remains attraction. Now
>   consider a small positive mass $\textbf{m}_+$ in the field of a nearby
>   large negative mass $\textbf{M}_-$. In this situation, the
>   gravitational field of $\textbf{M}_-$ is repulsive, as Bondi has
>   calculated, and $\textbf{m}_+$ is pushed away from $\textbf{M}_-$. If
>   we substitute a small negative mass $\textbf{m}_-$ for $\textbf{m}_+$,
>   the result is the same because of the reversal of both gravitational
>   and inertial mass, as described above. So $\textbf{M}_-$ repels all
>   masses, positive or negative.
>
> There is a curious corollary of this result, which Bondi pointed out
>   in his paper. Consider a pair of equal and opposite positive and a
>   negative mass placed close to each other. The negative mass is
>   attracted to the positive mass, while the positive mass is repelled by
>   the negative mass. Thus the two masses will experience equal forces
>   and accelerations in the same direction (in violation of Newton's
>   third law) and the system of two particles will accelerate, seemingly
>   without limit. The negative mass will chase the positive mass with
>   constant acceleration.

He also mentions in the next paragraph that "The net mass-energy of equal positive and negative masses will be zero."